# Git merging branches after unmerging

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm having problems with git merge. I have 2 branches, develop and feature. What I did:

1. I merged feature into develop by mistake, and so I unmerged it ( git revert -m 1 )
2. I merged develop into feature, but it deleted all the code changes in my feature branch, so I unmerged the merged ( git revert -m 1 )
3. I try to create another merge from develop to feature, it shows no changes.

Now, how do I merged develop into my feature branch with all the code in develop and not lose code in feature?

Comment: Which branch were you on when unmerging in step 1?

Comment: What did you expect to be the difference between steps 2 and 3?

Comment: created a reconcile branch off feature, merged develop into it, then it got merged to develop.

Comment: Can you just look at the output of `gitk --all` or the like? It should become apparent what situation you're in and what you need to do next.

Comment: You need to stop thrashing around and breaking stuff! — Reverting a merge does _not_ "undo" the merge. You cannot re-merge a reverted merge. See, always see: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt It explains exactly what the reason is, and what you can do instead.

Comment: To clarify @matt's comment, reverting a commit undoes the *changes* brought in by that commit, but the commit remains. Similarly, reverting a **merge** commit undoes the *changes* brought in by that merge, but all the commits remain. This is why you can't merge the same commits in again; they are already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by now you understand that you can't merge the same commit IDs in again after reverting the merge, because those commit IDs are already in the history. In order to merge them in again you will need to give them new commit IDs.

In general, if you mess up something on a shared branch such as `develop`, then unless you catch it immediately, reset it and can force push out the fix before other people start using it or merging other things in, then reverting, like you did, is probably the best course of action there.

However, for **your own** feature branch, generally you would not need to revert since you can just rewrite your own branch however you please, without affecting anyone else. If you can rewrite your branch, then instead of merging the latest `develop` into it, it's slightly cleaner to just rebase your own branch onto the latest `develop`. If you hadn't already merged your branch into `develop` you could normally do this with your branch checked out already:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
```

You can do that anytime you wish. (I probably do it at least a few times per day in active repos.)

In your current situation, you won't be able to do that because the commit IDs on your branch are already in `develop`. So this first time, you'll need to do this instead (with your branch checked out already):

```
git fetch
git reset --hard <commit-before-merge-of-develop>
# Now use a fancy rebase to rewrite your branch on top of develop
git rebase --onto origin/develop <original-commit-from-develop>
```

Note that `<commit-before-merge-of-develop>` represents the commit ID on your branch before you merged in `develop`, and `<original-commit-from-develop>` represents the original merge-base of your branch with `develop` before you merged it into `develop` accidentally. In other words, this is the parent of the first *new* commit on your branch. The "fancy" rebase will rewrite all the *new* commit IDs on your branch so you can then merge them into `develop` again whenever you are ready.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, go back to the commit on develop before the one where you merged the feature branch. Then, force-push it to the hosted repository:

```
# check out the (local) develop branch first
git checkout develop
# go back the commit you want to end up in there
git reset --hard abc123def456
# push it to the remote
git push --force-with-lease origin HEAD:develop
```

Now, you still have the messed up feature branch. For that, you effectively do the same. Note that if you don't have a remote branch, the last step is left out.

That said, if you think you are missing some commits somewhere, check out `git reflog`. From that, you can re-trace most changes you made to the repo. If you find a commit there that's missing, you can `git cherry-pick` it into whichever branch you want.

Comment: so there's alot of new merges in the develop branch right now( after the unmerge ), would doing this remove them all?

Comment: Yes, of course. In any case, you can always try out things locally. If you think you messed up, you can always use e.g. `git reset --hard origin/develop` to get your branch back to what the develop branch on gitlab is.